# UEFI Variable Storage (removing /sys/firmware/efi dump files) when Kernel Variables CONFIG_EFIVAR_FS & CONFIG_EFI_VARS both =y as in Ubuntu 20.04

Tags: uefi, environment-variables, linux-kernel, configure

In the [Arch Wiki](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#Linux_kernel_configuration_options_for_UEFI) I see that the two kernel variables `CONFIG_EFIVAR_FS` & `CONFIG_EFI_VARS` should be set `=y` and `=n` respectively.  Arch says, "This option should be disabled to prevent any potential issues with both efivarfs and sysfs-efivars enabled."  In Ubuntu 20.04, they are both set to `=y`.  If I am understanding correctly, it appears that as a result, I have both `dump-*` files in `/sys/firmware/efi/efivars` and `dump-*` directories in `/sys/firmware/efi/vars`.

```
$ ls -l efivars/dump*
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 644 Feb 27 00:12 efivars/dump-type0-10-1-1645912016-C-cfc8fc79-be2e-4ddc-97f0-9f98bfe298a0
[& etc.]

$ ls -l vars/dump*
vars/dump-type0-10-1-1645912016-C-cfc8fc79-be2e-4ddc-97f0-9f98bfe298a0:
total 0
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 00:48 attributes
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 00:48 data
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 00:48 guid
-rw------- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 00:48 raw_var
-r-------- 1 root root 4096 Feb 27 00:48 size
[& etc.]
```

As my NVRAM has been filled up with these (see [here](https://superuser.com/questions/1081537/lenovo-thinkpad-t450s-error-the-non-volatile-system-uefi-variable-storage-is/1081559) and [here](https://gist.github.com/roadkell/9e98db6656e28fbbf1bf51082040f67f) for troubles due to the `acpi-call` package, particularly in aging Thinkpads - mine is a W530), I am wondering if my understanding is correct, and that therefore I need to remove both the files and the directories with their contents?

**Edit1:** Following user1686's answer, I tried deleting `../efivars/dump*`.  Even after a reboot, the `../vars/dump*` directories remain.  Worse, the `../efivars/dump*` files are back!

**Edit2:**  I deleted `../efivars/dump*` for a second time and after reboot they are now gone, along with the `../vars/dump*` directories.

Answer (score 1):

Both locations represent the same thing – they're different views into the same EFI "variable" store, and there's only one copy of that variable under the hood.

So whichever one you remove first, the kernel will ask the EFI Runtime Services to delete the exact same EFI variable either way, and the entry should disappear from both locations at once.

(If it *doesn't* disappear from both locations, don't try to delete it from the other, instead reboot.)

Comment: Alright, thank you, *but* it has not yet been deleted from both locations.  I will try a reboot, though I am a bit anxious because others have reported bricked machines due to full NVRAM even after deleting .../efivars.  I won't reboot right away, but will report back after I do.

Comment: Ok, so that didn't work.  I rebooted and not only do the ../vars/dump-* directories remain, but the ../efivars/dump-* files are all back!  Do you have any other thoughts?

Comment: Try deleting it from the other location instead (though I'd be surprised if it gave different results...), _or_ if you can start the EFI Shell (whether built-in or downloadable), try its `dmpstore` command to delete variables. In the worst case, reset all firmware settings.

Comment: EFI shell - I think you're referring to getting into the interface at post time, yes?  There is no way to delete via the BIOS (which is what Thinkpads of this era provide).  What would it mean to download an EFI shell?  (Oh, and when I try deleting from the other location, I should be rm -r dump*, yes?  Deleting the whole directory and its contents?)

Comment: I mean it's literally a command-line shell, much like bash or Cmd, only running in the "raw" EFI environment. Depending on manufacturer, it's _sometimes_ embedded in the firmware, but more commonly you have to [download](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/Unified_Extensible_Firmware_Interface#UEFI_Shell) the .efi file for it.

Comment: Thanks.  Now strangely, deleting ../efivars/dump* a *second* time and rebooting, did clear them.  I'm not sure what to make of that, but I'm certainly happy.  I'm going to look into how to use this EFI shell anyway.  Quite a black box down there.  I really need to do coreboot ...